# SQL Server: SELECT * INTO takes forever to run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to generate a temporary table using a SELECT INTO statement using a syntax like the following:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Zipcode]
INTO [PeopleAndPlaces]
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID
```

This query seems to run indefinitely (over 2 hours now with no result). However, if I run just a select statement:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Zipcode]
--INTO [PeopleAndPlaces]
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID
```

The query completes in ~4 minutes. How is this possible?

As an additional check I tried running the query for a smaller set, both with and without the into clause:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Zipcode]
INTO [PeopleAndPlaces]
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID;
WHERE [Zipcode] = '1000'

SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Zipcode]
--INTO [PeopleAndPlaces]
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID
WHERE [Zipcode] = '1000'
```

Both of these queries take about 10 seconds to complete, which leads me to believe that the create of the table doesn't necessarily take longer than simply displaying the results.

Comment: What do the query plans look like for the two queries with wildly different runtimes? How many rows are we talking about?

Comment: What's the definition fro PeopleAndPlaces? What are it's indexes, constraints and triggers?

Comment: I suggest you: 1. Run sp_who2 and observe activity. 2. Run your query above. 3. While your query is running, run sp_who2 in another window and observe the difference. You're waiting for something and sp_who2 will tell you what (though it can be pretty cryptic). Please post your results.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you're trying to create a temporary table, but I don't see the requisite `#` before `[PeopleAndPlaces]`. Try updating your query to this:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [Zipcode]
INTO [#PeopleAndPlaces]
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID
```

Update, I tried your version of the query in my db, and it doesn't run forever, so I would look at your result set. How long does this take to run?

```
SELECT *
FROM [FirstNames] F
LEFT JOIN [LastNames] L  on F.ID = L.ID
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodes] Z on Z.ID = L.ID
```

Comment: note that `[#PeopleAndPlaces]` does not create a temp table. It creates a normal table called `#PeopleAndPlaces`.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid must be different in different versions of SQL Server. I just tested again, and it definitely creates a temp table.

Comment: OH! I admit I just posted that without checking because `[` is meant to 'escape' the name but clearly it doesn't in this case - I stand corrected.